# 2Checkout Webhook Java

Tags: jersey-2.0, 2checkout

I am using 2CheckOut Sandbox account. I am trying to work with webhooks

I am using the following jersey code to be called when the order is completed.

```
  @POST
  @Path("/webhook")
  @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
   public String hello(@Context ContainerRequestContext crc) {
        System.out.println("received");
        return "success";
    }
```

I have Enabled 2CheckOut Order created Notification and have provided my url as : `localhost:8080/demo/payment/webhook`.

But my API is not getting called , what I am doing wrong here , another question is what should I provide in the `@Consumes`.

Comment: To '@Consumes' you should put the MediaType that your API is expecting from the request (Content-Type header) to that endpoint. If the request's is Content-Type of application/json your API should '@Consume' MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON if the request's is Content-Type is XML your API '@Consumes' will be MediaType.APPLICATION_XML.